# why is the AfxMessageBox Displaying chinese characters

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

This code displays hello in chinese

```
char buffer[10]="hello";
AfxMessageBox((LPCTSTR)buffer);
```

while this code displays it in english

```
AfxMessageBox(L"hello");
```

Could someone tell me how do i type cast the buffer variable properly if that is the problem in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LPCTSTR type is a Long Pointer to a Transparent STRing.
What's important here is the T, Transparent (at least I think the T stands for Transparent).

If your application is compiled as an ASCII application, all T types (like TCHAR) are redefined as their ASCII-counterpart.  So TCHAR will become simply char.

If your application is compiled as Unicode, all T types are redefined as Unicode types.  TCHAR becomes wchar_t.

The same is true for all Windows (and MFC) functions.  All Windows functions come in 2 variants, an ASCII version (e.g. MessageBoxA) and a Unicode version (e.g. MessageBoxW).  MessageBox itself is nothing more than a define to either MessageBoxA or MessageBoxW (depending on how you compile).

In your example, buffer is defined as a char-vector type, but you convert it to a pointer to a transparent type.  I assume that your application is compiled in Unicode, so LPCTSTR is actually a "wchar_t *".  So this cast is incorrect.

Prepending the "hello" string with L, tells the compiler to theat the constant "hello" as a Unicode string, which makes it the correct type to be passed to the Unicode version of AfxMessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` flag defined in your compiler options then casting the string `LPCTSTR` will treat the string as an unicode string. In case windows, it will treat every 16 bytes as a single character and tries to find the corresponding unicode character. To make it display english character, use `TCHAR` while defining the array.